# Escaping 'echo' in batch files

Tags: bash, shell, command, dos, echo

I'm trying to create a bash command file on the fly from within an Windows 7 DOS shell:

```
:: inside the .BAT file ..
:: check we are in the right directory
echo pwd > command.txt
:: get the shell to echo its environment variables
:: !!!! How do I get around this ... ?
echo echo $PWD
```

I thought prefixing the second echo command with a ^ (caret) would work but no. What is the solution?

Answer (score 3):

I just tried

@echo echo %TMP%

which returned

echo C:\Users\Spike\AppData\Local\Temp

I think the problem wasn't the echo so much as the $PWD. %% is DOS for $.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me on Windows XP,

```
@echo off
:: inside the .BAT file ..
:: check we are in the right directory
echo pwd > command.txt
:: get the shell to echo its environment variables
:: !!!! How do I get around this ... ?
echo echo ^$PWD >>command.txt
```

**Output**

```
C:\test>test.bat

C:\test>more command.txt
pwd
echo $PWD
```